# jQuery/javascript not producing desired effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I am trying to employ the following code to do as follows:

If the user is viewing the site on a mobile device, hide a header div. If the user is not viewing the site on a mobile device (i.e., they are using a desktop), refresh the page on browser resize. However, neither aspect is functioning on either desktop or mobile devices.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

The jQuery version I've called is 1.10.2 and the Detect Mobile Browser jQuery script file is from here: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/download/jquery

```
<script src='scripts/detectmobilebrowser-min.js'></script>
<script>
var isMobile = $.browser.mobile(http://www.mywebsite.com/)
if (isMobile) {
$('#secondary-header').css('display','none');
}
else {
$(window).on('resize',function(){window.location.assign("http://www.mywebsite.com/");});
}
</script>
```

Comment: CSS Media queries!  Makes no sense to use JavaScript. Yikes on the resize code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into a `TypeError: jQuery.browser.mobile is not a function`
**cause the script you're using is not a function** so does not accepts arguments either:

```
var isMobile = $.browser.mobile; // boolean true/false
```

is a way to be used.

Additionally I would discourage you to send visitors to i.e: `m.mywebsite.com` just cause they *resized* the window...

Comment: Thank you! That solved one problem. FYI, one reason I refresh the viewport is, although my site is responsive, some heading elements don't align all that cleanly when the window is dynamically resized (e.g., by "shrinking" it using a mouse pulling inward at one corner). 

Otherwise, the #secondary-header div is still visible when I view the site on my iphone/ipad, so for some reason the other jQuery function doesn't seem to be working. FYI, the script comes after calling my CSS file in the header.

Comment: @NewGuy place your `<script>` tag just before the closing `</body>` tag and it should work. Or wrap your jQuery script inside `document.ready` like: `$(function(){ /*put all here!! */ });`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing the quotes in

```
var isMobile = $.browser.mobile("http://www.mywebsite.com/")
```